# Checking Poker Hands

Tags: java, poker

I been having some issues checking poker hands. So in this code we choose how many decks we want to play with and then the rest is like video poker. My issue is that some of the hands checked are "seen". For the straight, I assume because I have it set as though my arraylist is sorted by assumption, how would I fix that?

Also, for two pair, my friend said that a few times it would not properly check if I actually had the two pair, saying it wasn't checking correctly. Here are my check algorithms, can anyone tell me how to fix them? Also, if there are any problems you see besides the straight and two pair having issues. I haven't hit full house or greater yet to test. The .get(#) gets the card suit or rank (getsuit or getrank) from my hand (arraylist). I also think my royal flush may be incorrect.

```
private boolean flush(){
        if (currentHand.get(0).getSuit() == currentHand.get(1).getSuit()
                && currentHand.get(1).getSuit() == currentHand.get(2).getSuit()
                && currentHand.get(2).getSuit() == currentHand.get(3).getSuit()
                && currentHand.get(3).getSuit() == currentHand.get(4).getSuit()){
        return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean royal(){

            if ((currentHand.get(0).getRank() == 1)
                    && (currentHand.get(1).getRank() == 10)
                    && (currentHand.get(2).getRank() == 11)
                    && (currentHand.get(3).getRank() == 12)
                    && (currentHand.get(4).getRank() == 13)) {

                return true;

            }
        return false;
    }
    private boolean straight(){//look up
        if (currentHand.get(0).getRank() + 1 == currentHand.get(1).getRank()
                    && currentHand.get(1).getRank() + 1 == currentHand.get(2).getRank()
                    && currentHand.get(2).getRank() + 1 == currentHand.get(3).getRank()
                    && currentHand.get(3).getRank() + 1 == currentHand.get(4).getRank()) {

        return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
    private boolean four(){
        if (currentHand.get(0).getRank() == currentHand.get(1).getRank()
                && currentHand.get(1).getRank() == currentHand.get(2).getRank()
                && currentHand.get(2).getRank() == currentHand.get(3).getRank()) {
            return true;
        } else if (currentHand.get(1).getRank() == currentHand.get(2).getRank()
                && currentHand.get(2).getRank() == currentHand.get(3).getRank()
                && currentHand.get(3).getRank() == currentHand.get(4).getRank()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
    private boolean fullHouse() {
        if (currentHand.get(0).getRank() == currentHand.get(1).getRank()
                && currentHand.get(1).getRank() == currentHand.get(2).getRank()) {
            if (currentHand.get(3).getRank() == currentHand.get(4).getRank()) {

                return true;
            }


        }else if(currentHand.get(0).getRank() == currentHand.get(1).getRank()){
            if(currentHand.get(2).getRank() == currentHand.get(3).getRank()
                && currentHand.get(3).getRank() == currentHand.get(4).getRank()){
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
    private boolean threeOfKind(){
        if ((currentHand.get(0).getRank() == currentHand.get(1).getRank()
                && currentHand.get(1).getRank() == currentHand.get(2).getRank())
                || (currentHand.get(1).getRank() == currentHand.get(2).getRank()
                && currentHand.get(2).getRank() == currentHand.get(3).getRank())
                || (currentHand.get(2).getRank() == currentHand.get(3).getRank()
                && currentHand.get(3).getRank() == currentHand.get(4).getRank())){
        return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    private boolean twoPair() {
        if (currentHand.get(0).getRank() == currentHand.get(1).getRank()
                && currentHand.get(2).getRank() == currentHand.get(3).getRank()){
            return true;
        }


            else if((currentHand.get(1).getRank() == currentHand.get(2).getRank())&&
            (currentHand.get(3).getRank() == currentHand.get(4).getRank())){
                return true;
            }

           else if((currentHand.get(0).getRank() == currentHand.get(1).getRank())&&
            (currentHand.get(3).getRank() == currentHand.get(4).getRank())){
                return true;
            }else

        return false;
    }
    private boolean jackOrBetter() {
        for (int i = 11; i <= 14; i++) {
            int comp;
            if (i == 14)
                comp =1;
            else comp = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (currentHand.get(j).getRank() ==comp ) {
                    if (currentHand.get(j).getRank() == currentHand.get(j + 1).getRank()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
```

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: `royal()` definitely seems incorrect. e.g. is there any reason that `currentHand.get(0) == 10` and `currentHand(1) == 1` wouldn't be a royal flush if you also had values of 11, 12 and 13 on the other cards? If not, you need a loop for doing this check.

Answer (score 4):

Typically the kind of code you'll find in the known (and very fast) poker evaluators are much lower-level than that: no fancy OO or anything like that. Just plain fast bit manipulation and crazy, crazy fast table lookups. The fast hand evaluators out there can evaluate hundreds of millions (!) of hands... Per second! But let's leave that aside and start from your OOish code.

I take it you want a five cards evaluator and then if you play, say, Texas Hold'em then you're going to test the C(7,5), which gives 21, possible ways to take 5 cards out of seven (5 on the board + 2 holecards). And keep the best hand.

So on to your five-cards evaluator.

A "trick" is simplify your job by keeping intermediate information. Your logic is then greatly simplified.

Here's one way you could do it (once again: this is an over-simplification compared to real fast evaluators but it should help you get the job done):

```
final boolean isFlush = flush();
final int[] nbPerRank = findNumberForEachRank();
final boolean isStraight = straight( nbPerRank );
```

Where the `nbPerRank` array for, say, "Queens full of five" (three queens and two fives) may look like this:

```
;                   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  T  J  Q  K  A  

int[] nbPerRank = [ 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0 ]
```

Then your main method shall look a bit like this:

```
if ( isStraight ) {
    final int highCard = findStraightHighCard();
    if ( isFlush ) {
        if ( highCard == 13 ) {     // starting with the 'A'
            System.out.println( "You have a royal flush" );
        else if ( highCard = 4 ) {  // starting with the '5'
            System.out.println( "You have a wheel straight flush" );  
        } else {
            System.out.println( "You have a straight flush " );
        }
     } else {
        ... // rinse and repeat for normal straight
     }
 } else {
    ...
```

Note that seen that your evaluator is a 5 card evaluator, once you have a straight you know there are only two possible cases: straight and straight flush (with five cards, it is impossible to have even a pair if you already have a straight with these five cards).

So by now you already have taken the straight flush and the straight into account, you now need to check, in order, for :

- four of a kind
- full house / boat
- flush (but not straight flush anymore)
- set
- two pairs
- one pair

To check if you have four of kind you then see if you have the number 4 in your `nbPerRank` `int` array.

Pseudo-code could be like this:

```
// no need to test for straight an straight flush anymore...
if ( hasFourSameRank ) {
   " You have four of a kind ";
} else if ( hasThreeSameRank && hasTwoSameRank ) {
    " You have a full house ";
} else if ( isFlush ) {
    " You have a flush";
} else if ( hasThreeSameRank ) {
    " You have a set ";
} else if ( hasTwoSameRank ) {
    // two possible cases here: two pairs or one pair
    if ( hasTwoPairs ) {
        "You have two pairs";
    } else {
        "You have one pair";
} else {
    "You have no pair";
}
```

The nested if / else are quite normal in such evaluators (at least the ones not using lookup tables / LUT).

Note that this is just one way to do it. You can go "fancier" and instead of returning simply an int[] containing the number of each card per rank you can also return the max card, the max number of similar rank, etc.

You'll then have to find a way to assign a value (hence the "evaluator" name) for each hand, so that *"two pairs, eights and deuces, kicker jack"* beats *"two pairs, eights and deuces, kicker nine"* etc.

But this should get you started.

Another solution would be to simply reuse one of the existing evaluator out there (which, in addition to be tried and tested, shall be really fast: it's only bit manipulation and lookup tables, no slow OO).

(slightly related) you may also want to read my old answer here: [On Two Plus Two poker hand evaluator, how do you get the best 5 cards combination out of the 7 that you passed to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935212)

Comment: maybe you mean `if ( highCard == 13 )` not `if ( highCard = 13 )`, too for = 4.

Comment: @MarcoLopezAcierno: yes thanks, edited.  I also considered that his cards were one-based and not zero-based (because in his question OP his using one-based and not zero-based), which is why the ace in my example is 13 and not 12.

Comment: Where you want to put bitwise operations? there are no operations at all.

Comment: For the lookup tables, it seems to me, that the time you need to construct the lookup value, is the same as checking the hand.